# Index Match with same Data Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Master Sheet and several data sheets with same template. I use VBA to copy the data value on column C or E all sheets based on the data availability (If C blank then copy E, If C have data than copy C skip E) to column C at the master sheet. After the data on column C or E copied, I use VBA to insert Index Match function to copy additional data based on the copied data. The problem is that the data sometimes have the same value to lookup (i.e. "Laptop" available on Sheet A and Sheet C) in which Index Match always take the first sheet that contain the the data (the Laptop on Sheet A only) so both additional data are copied based on Sheet A only.

How can I make the Index Match to take the data based on the sheet location with same data?

I attach what it looks like and what I expect

What it looks like now (take a look on the laptop and column A B)

[image: what it is look now]

What I expect (same, on laptop and column A B)

[image: expected outcome]

this is the code that I use

```
Sub Details() 

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'COA
Sheets(2).Range("A6").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX('ACF'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'ACF'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('ACF'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'ACF'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('BIGBIKE'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('BIGBIKE'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('BOD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BOD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('BOD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BOD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('CORPSEC'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('CORPSEC'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('DIGITAL'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('DIGITAL'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('GDG'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'GDG'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('GDG'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'GDG'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('HC3'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HC3'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('HC3'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HC3'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('HRGA'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('HRGA'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('IT'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'IT'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('IT'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'IT'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('LDD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'LDD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('LDD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'LDD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('MCD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MCD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('MCD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MCD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('MSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MSD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('MSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MSD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('NPD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'NPD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('NPD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'NPD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('PARTS'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('PARTS'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('PURCHASING'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('PURCHASING'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('TSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'TSD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),INDEX('TSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'TSD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"

'Div
Sheets(2).Range("B6").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFERROR(INDEX('ACF'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'ACF'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('ACF'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'ACF'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('BIGBIKE'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('BIGBIKE'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BIGBIKE'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('BOD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BOD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('BOD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'BOD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('CORPSEC'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('CORPSEC'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'CORPSEC'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('DIGITAL'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('DIGITAL'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'DIGITAL'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('GDG'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'GDG'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('GDG'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'GDG'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('HC3'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HC3'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('HC3'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HC3'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('HRGA'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('HRGA'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'HRGA'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('IT'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'IT'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('IT'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'IT'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('LDD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'LDD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('LDD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'LDD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('MCD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MCD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('MCD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MCD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('MSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MSD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('MSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'MSD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('NPD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'NPD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('NPD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'NPD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('PARTS'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('PARTS'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PARTS'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('PURCHASING'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),IFERROR(INDEX('PURCHASING'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'PURCHASING'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
",IFERROR(INDEX('TSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'TSD'!R6C3:R2000C3,0)),INDEX('TSD'!R6C:R2000C,MATCH(RC3,'TSD'!R6C5:R2000C5,0))" & _
")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"

end sub
```

Comment: Again, I am not able to understand what you try accomplishing... Of course, I cannot waste my time trying to understand your sausage formulas. I am trying to understand the question reading **the words**. You say: "Match always take the first sheet that contain the the data". And so what? This is the normal way of this function behavior. **What would you like it (or something else) to behave**? You show us two pictures which look to differ only on the last row, "A" column value? What do you expect from us after looking to these pictures?

Comment: Do you want (anything) returning **based on concatenation between "A" and "B" columns**? Even if so, what connection is between that and your problem regarding returning only from the first (probably, iterated) sheet? Should we understand that what you name data, is not exactly the same, it differs in "A:A" column? I also feel the need to emphasize that if you edit the question and bring some clarifications **after some hours**, we do not spend our time continuously checking what you did with the question. Our enthusiasm and wish to help you, in such circumstances, is diminishing considerably.

Comment: @FaneDuru I'm very new to VBA so I can't create complex code so I just inserting Index Match formula to VBA. What I try to achieve is that if there're 2 datas with the same value lets say that from my picture is laptop. Index Match formula always take the first sheet that is mentioned on the formula and in my case its the "ACF" sheet. What I want is that if the first laptop already taken, the function will go to the next sheet that contain laptop and take the detail on.

Comment: it's just not column A and B only but there is another columns that are similar but using the vlookup formula and of course, I can't ask that all so I just cut it only 2 columns so that I will work it out for other data by myself

Comment: It is not a matter of VBA skills level. Only a matter of explaining **in words**. If we do not understand what you try doing, we cannot help. Simple... Which is the purpose of showing us the two pictures? What should we understand from "take a look on the laptop and column A B"? Where should your code returning the next occurrence, if the first one is taken? To overwrite the previous found one? If  not, where? How to be helped if you are not able to explain **in words** what you try accomplishing? Forget about your code now...

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have multiple data sheets and you want to copy all the data into one master sheet but with the following stipulation: Column C on the master sheet will hold a value from your data sheets, if Column C has a value then use this, otherwise use the value from column E.  As for the issue you are having, the code you have created is unable to identify the original data row, coping across the wrong data?

Comment: As to answer this question, a reliable way would be to have a unique ID for every row of data and use this for the reference for gathering data at a later time. Or if it is a one time only copy, then copy the data for each row all at the same time whilst making the adjustment for either Column C or E values.